# Viewing Xbox One Network Traffic

Tags: wireshark

I am trying to view the HTTP/HTTPS traffic going from my XBOX one so I can see what is being requested.  I started off trying to use Charles proxy like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MP4ZcwSHxbw.  However there is no option to use a proxy on xbox one, so I could not use this method.

I am now trying to use wireshark, with my xbox connected to my PC's internet using an ethernet cable.  I can see HTTP requests from my xbox, but cannot see any information about HTTPS not even the URL that is being called.

Does anyone know how I can decrypt this traffic in WireShark?  Or a better way of viewing the network traffic from my Xbox One?

Thanks,

Comment: Thank you for asking.  Sadly the community voted this off topic; please ask on [su]

Answer (score 1):

This is the entire point of HTTP**S**. A man-in-the-middle cannot know what is being passed between systems. A "proxy" will not help if the system is checking the validity of the SSL certificate(s).

(Without the *server certificate*, you cannot decode any of that traffic.)

Comment: Thanks for answering, that makes sense.  However, do you know of a way that I can get my XBOX's HTTP requests to go to my proxy, instead of straight to the server?  Either by internet sharing with my PC/MAC or any other way?  Thanks